# Any workaround to extract plain text data in ASCII from `netCDF` file in R

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, ascii, climate

I am wondering about how to proportionally split or subset the gridded dataset in `netCDF` format where data sources were provided by `European Climate Assessments and dataset` ([link for data source](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php)). However, `E-OBS` climate gridded dataset were given for each `15` years climate observation throughout Europe and working with big `netCDF` format grid data in R always cause memory problem in my site when I tried to treat all missing values. After decompressing grid data in `netCDF` format ([download link of grid data](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/tg_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc.gz)), I used `raster::stack` to import whole gridded data, then I tried to treat missing values in this grid data because I need to do some statistics on this temperature observation later on, but it caused memory problem. So here is what in R:

```
mydat <- raster::stack("~/data/tg_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc")
> print(mydat)
File C:\Users\jvrat\Documents\stella\data\tg_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

     1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        short tg[longitude,latitude,time]   
            long_name: mean temperature
            units: Celsius
            standard_name: air_temperature
            _FillValue: -9999
            scale_factor: 0.00999999977648258

     3 dimensions:
        longitude  Size:464
            long_name: Longitude values
            units: degrees_east
            standard_name: longitude
        latitude  Size:201
            long_name: Latitude values
            units: degrees_north
            standard_name: latitude
        time  Size:5479   *** is unlimited ***
            long_name: Time in days
            units: days since 1950-01-01 00:00
            standard_name: time

    5 global attributes:
        Ensembles_ECAD: 17.0
        Conventions: CF-1.4
        References: http://www.ecad.eu\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/ensembles.php\nhttp://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/Haylock_et_al_2008.pdf
        history: Wed Apr  4 11:17:28 2018: ncks -a -d time,10957,16435 tg_0.25deg_regular_1.nc tg_0.25deg_reg_1980-1994_v17.0.nc
Wed Apr  4 11:16:02 2018: ncks -a --mk_rec_dmn time tg_0.25deg_regular.nc tg_0.25deg_regular_1.nc
        NCO: 4.6.7

mydat <- raster::reclassify(mydat, cbind(NA, -999))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.9 Gb
```

To avoid this memory problem, perhaps I can try to split original gridded data in `netCDF` format in `10` years and `5` years observation or equally split the grid data by each `5` years climate data observation (originally it was 15 years climate data observation for whole Europe). But doing this way is not feasible and desired.

**UPDATE: objective**:

I want to either convert this `netCDF` file to plain text tabular data in `ASCII` format (extract plain text data of Germany grid from chosen `E-OBS` `netCDF` grid data). I can use `R` to work with this data manipulation, then I will use its output data (plain text data in `ASCII`) in `ArcGIS desk` for different interpolation.

**UPDATE 2**:

I need to extract plain text data of Germany grid with `0.25 degree` resolution from original `E-OBS` `netCDF` files where 15 years climate observation for whole Europe were stored in each `nc` file. I need all grid data in `ASCII` format or `csv` format because I can import them with `ArcGIS` desktop and apply respective geospatial analysis. I need to find a solution how to get this task done that I specified above. Any idea please?

How can I make this happen this extraction or possible coercion of `netCDF` data? Is that doable in R? Any more thoughts?

Comment: @mdsumner please take a look my updated post. Basically, I want to extract plain text data of Germany' grid from chosen `netCDF` files. Any way to get this done in R or other tools? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to work with these data in R? Then only do the resetting of values with the a slice at a time. See how `mydat[[1]]` compares to `mydat`.

Are you going to work with it as a NetCDF elsewhere? R's raster is not a good tool for creating a new NetCDF file or modifying one. See `ncdf4` or `RNetCDF` package for that.

If in R, `reclassify` is the wrong tool I think, that requires three values per column, a `from`, `to` interval and the `new` to assign those.

Do you want to replace -999 with `NA`? Then you need something like

```
r <- mydat[[1]]; r[r == -999] <- NA;
```

and then a way to write out each slice to a new data set.

See `vignette("functions")` for other approaches for large data.

Comment: working with this data in R is to get only particular grid data, then work with its output in `ArcGIS` desktop. For chosen `E-OBS` grid data of whole Europe, I want to extract plain text data in `ASCII` format from `netCDF` file. The purpose of doing that is I intend to do yearly statistics for all grid observations of Germany. I know how to crop Germany's grid, but I need to treat missing values before the clipping.Could you elaborate your motivation please?

Comment: Is this only one layer? I would crop before changing the values. `r <- crop(mydat, extent(<of-germany>))` r[r == -999] <- NA` - if it's more than one layer, let us know. Put the output of `print(mydat)` in the question please.

Comment: it is not only one layer, in total `5497` layer in `rasterstack` object, please take a look updated post. Any possible update on your solution? Thank you !

Comment: It's all pretty straightforward in R, see ?raster::crop ?raster::subset ?raster::as.data.frame and ?raster::writeRaster - as it stands your question can't be answered without going and doing everything, it's too much to guess at - I suggest trying each of these things in the small so you learn about the tools available to you. Reclassify is the wrong function, and `mydat[mydat == -999] <- NA` might be enough, but do your cropping first.